# My package manager doesn't work after I upgrade

Tags: linux, mysql, apt, dpkg

I don't know why my package manager is not fully working.

```bash
halil@ubuntu:Downloads$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-template-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libldns-dev python2.7-minimal maven libldns3 imagemagick libavcodec-extra
  libjs-jquery-ui libmaven3-core-java libavdevice58 libdcmtk16 libopenexr25
  libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra php-twig libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  libavcodec-extra58 libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common libavformat58
  python2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  krb5-locales libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libmysqlclient21 mysql-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:amd64.postinst: /usr/share/glib-2.0/clean-up-unmanaged-libraries: /bin/dash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:amd64.postinst: Trying cleanup again with more logging...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:amd64.postinst: /usr/share/glib-2.0/clean-up-unmanaged-libraries: /bin/dash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libglib2.0-0:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:i386.postinst: /usr/share/glib-2.0/clean-up-unmanaged-libraries: /bin/dash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:i386.postinst: Trying cleanup again with more logging...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:i386.postinst: /usr/share/glib-2.0/clean-up-unmanaged-libraries: /bin/dash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 installed libglib2.0-0:i386 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64:
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.65.1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configurat
ion of obs-studio:
 obs-studio depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package obs-studio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems 
prevent configuration of libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64:
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.65.1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.70.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:
 code depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 code depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package code (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0 (= 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.70.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 depends on gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 (= 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (= 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependencyNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                        problems - lea
ving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shared-mime-info:
 shared-mime-info depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shared-mime-info (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for desktop-file-utils:
 desktop-file-utils depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:amd64
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64
 obs-studio
 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64
 code
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64
 shared-mime-info
 desktop-file-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: As always, NOT a problem with APT. ***10 not fully installed or removed*** is the problem. Now you have to 1) check and eventually correct your software sources and 2) try to reinstall everything mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: For Ubuntu, see this guide *How to Prevent and Fix Package Dependency Errors*, https://linuxhint.com/prevent_fix_package_dependency_errors_ubuntu/